# How to find the maximum length of a key in NSMutableDictionary?

Tags: objective-c

My dictionary looks like this

```
@{@"Blue": @"Big", 
@"Red": @"medium",
@"Yellow": @"small"}
```

I would like to know that the highest key length is 6, because Yellow is the longest key

Comment: … how to proceed when 2 keys are the same length ?

Comment: I'm not bothered. I just need to know the maximum length

Comment: Ah sorry I misunderstood, I thought you actually wanted to know what keys are the longest but you only need a number :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this. Suppose a is your dictionary. You can find the source here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/CollectionOperators.html

```
NSArray *array = a.allKeys;
NSNumber* maxLength= [array valueForKeyPath:@"@max.length"];
NSLog(@"Longest is %lu",maxLength.integerValue);
```